# Ambiguity in Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my test table:

```
CREATE TABLE [General].[Test]
(
[Name] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
[SSN] CHAR(10) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [UK_Test_SSN] 
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([SSN]) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF),
)
```

And I inserted some values:

```
INSERT INTO [General].[Test] ([SSN], [Name]) VALUES (N'901223476', N'Lol1'); 
INSERT INTO [General].[Test] ([SSN], [Name]) VALUES (N'2591830061', N'Lol2'); 
INSERT INTO [General].[Test] ([SSN], [Name]) VALUES (N'4431776273', N'Lol3'); 
INSERT INTO [General].[Test] ([SSN], [Name]) VALUES (N'987654321', N'Lol4');
INSERT INTO [General].[Test] ([SSN], [Name]) VALUES (N'123456789', N'Lol5');
INSERT INTO [General].[Test] ([SSN], [Name]) VALUES (N'0123456789', N'Lol6');
INSERT INTO [General].[Test] ([SSN], [Name]) VALUES (N'0012345678', N'Lol7');
INSERT INTO [General].[Test] ([SSN], [Name]) VALUES (N'123', N'Lol8');
```

And the first `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT
CASE 
  WHEN [T].[SSN] LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]',10) THEN [T].[SSN] 
  ELSE 1000000000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [T].[Name]) END AS [SSN]
FROM [General].[Test] AS [T];
GO
```

And the second query:

```
SELECT [T].[SSN] FROM [General].[Test] AS [T];
```

The ambiguity that I can't understand is about rows 6 and 7 whose `[SSN]` values start with 0

So for example about 6th row the first query returns `123456789` and second query return `0123456789`, can anyone explain why? And I really need to get the real value of `0123456789` in the first query, what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different datatypes being returned from your first column in the first query - in the first case, the `CHAR(10)` of the `[SSN]` is returned, in the `ELSE` case a large INT number. That's why SQL Server needs to convert one of the two datatypes to the other.

What you need to do, if you want to get back the `CHAR(10)`, is to `CAST` the second expression to that datatype:

```
SELECT
   CASE 
      WHEN [T].[SSN] LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]', 10) THEN [T].[SSN] 
      ELSE CAST(1000000000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [T].[Name]) AS CHAR(10)) 
   END
FROM [General].[Test] AS [T];
```

Then you get back your `CHAR(10)` values - and nothing gets converted to a INT (or BIGINT) and thus looses it's leading zeroes:

```
(No column name)
1000000001
2591830061
4431776273
1000000004
1000000005
0123456789
0012345678
1000000008
```